# Deserialization code security

Tags: java, security, serialization, deserialization

I have web server that retreive a serialized image sent from an applet.
The deserialization code is the following:

```
  //Http request from applet that contains serialized image 
  in = request.getInputStream();
  inputFromApplet = new ObjectInputStream(in);
  byte[] sendimage = (byte[]) inputFromApplet.readObject();
  //image is created then using byte[]
```

Is this code vulnerable to deserialization attacks ?
Thanks.

Comment: as much as any deserialization

Comment: What makes you think that this particular use of serialization would be any less vulnerable than another?

Comment: The cast to byte array can help perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the present comments. But there might be a special issue with the used ObjectInputStream. The type of the object that will be returned by the .readObject() method, is retrieved from the given serialization.

A malicious request could contain the serialization of an unexpected object. The ObjectInputStream will then read this data and the

> Classes [...] [will be]  loaded as required using the standard mechanisms.

As a result the following problems could occur:

- A simple ClassCastException
- Your application slows down and requires more memory for every loaded class
- Malicious code contained in the classes constructor could be invoked during the instantiation
- Malicious code contained in the classes initializer (if there is one) could be invoked during the instantiation

The probability of the last two things to happen is very low. This the required class with such code, must be available on your classpath.